# How to create a big tab system in JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this mockup page. The accordion works well but I would like to shows different pages with a  tab-like system. I would like to be able to click on the page 6, and then, the accordion content change dynamically.

It's impossible I think, to load all pages in hiddens div and to show it for naviguation. Because of the loading time It would need.

I would be able to send also a link to an item. By example, if I give the link http://example.com/#item-500 It would bring me to the page 400 (by example), item 500 and would open the tab. And I would like to just give a link to a page with any tab open. http://example.com/#page12

I try to figure out how to do this using JQuery and AJAX, but I don't see the solution.

How can I do this, without any page reload ?

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Would there be a consistent number of items per "tab?"

Comment: No that's the problem. Number of items and the number of tabs are non consistent..

Comment: Then what will determine the number of items on the tab?

Comment: for my knowledge, you cannot point any `#item` (a _div_ by nature) with URL if it has to be loaded by ajax dynamically, because browser only knows about the _divs_ that are statically present in a page

Comment: At max you can easily open required `page` by fetching URL parameters and loading Ajax page by jquery as per the request came.

Comment: Yeah I used var tabID = $('.linkClass')[0].toString().split('#')[1]; if someOne need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mathias-bank.de/jQuery/jquery.getParams.js) is a simple JQuery plugin to fetch URL parameters and [This](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2006/10/28/jquery-plugin-geturlparam/) is the tutorial, but either way you **cannot** point to a specific `item` on Ajax load with the URL.